# Application crashes when switching from application homescreen to other activity

Tags: android, android-emulator, crash, android-manifest

I have created my custom calendar widget inside my planning module of application. This calendar widget I have created and tested before, Now I have embedded it in my application. From my home screen when I call this my application getting crashed with following error logs. Also my onCreate getting called twice.

```
    `08-05 07:51:27.294: E/SurfaceFlinger(794): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
08-05 07:51:28.613: E/SurfaceFlinger(794): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
08-05 07:51:39.353: E/SurfaceFlinger(794): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
08-05 07:51:40.723: E/SurfaceFlinger(794): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
08-05 07:52:05.483: E/Trace(2246): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
08-05 07:52:05.513: E/SurfaceFlinger(794): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
08-05 07:52:07.814: E/SurfaceFlinger(794): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
08-05 07:52:10.624: E/Trace(2273): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
`
```

Comment: The logcat that you have posted does not include details of the crash

Comment: Please exactly what you want can you tell me? actually I am getting "error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2), ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property" these error's.

Comment: 08-05 07:11:30.630: E/Trace(4138): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2). this is error

Comment: @MohammodHossain yes I am getting this error before crash 08-05 07:44:06.636: E/Trace(1923): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

Comment: I think these are not exact error log cat

Comment: @MohammodHossain yes I have copied it just when I am running my application on emulator.

Comment: That message is quite common, and does not normally cause a crash.

Comment: @MohammodHossain please check I have updated my log cat trace results.

Comment: @Sheldon will you please check I have updated my log cat results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for your attention actually I have solved my problem, In my application I am applying custom font but my font size is "22 Mb" here is the actual problem . Solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

nativeGetEnabledTag error may be coming coz you may be using latest sdk (r21) and adt (21.0.0). Can you locat with this filter  ^(?!.*(nativeGetEnabledTags)).*$  and can send the crash logs.

Which version of android you are trying to build for? I hope you must have defined your calender in manifest file and should have given correct permissions in manifest..

Comment: Actually I created my own custom calendar widget. I am not using android calendar control.I am building my application for API level 17.

Comment: onCreate getting called twice hints that, maybe your screen orientation is happening. Is the crash someway realted to that? You can have a look at it. The log you have pasted is not related to your issue. It is coming coz you are using latest sdk + adt.. thats not a problem